# A live stream updating system like facebook

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am really stuck on this one , i got the system to work , but it actually refreshes the whole update stream per second ,this is my ajax request ,

```
setInterval(function(){
          $.ajax({type:"GET",url:"read_new_post.php?account_id="+currentuser,success:function(response){

                            $(".new_update").html(response);        
            }
        });
        },1000);
```

and this is my php script,imean that the echo part gets returned as response

```
if($i==0)
            {
                echo "<div class='new_update'></div>";
            }
        echo "
          <div id='post' postid=".$posts[$i]["postid"].">
                    <div id='poster_img'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/icons/Actions-list-add-user-icon.png' name='profile_img_for_post' width='40' id='profile_img_for_post' /><span id='poster_name'>".$poster_details[0]["firstname"]." ".$poster_details[0]["lastname"]."</span></div>
                    <div id='content'><br />
                    <span id='content_container'>".nl2br($posts[$i]["post_content"])."</span>
                    <br />
                    </div>
                    <div id='attributes'>
                        <span id='totallikes'><span id='like_dot' ></span>
<span id='text_tlikes'>10</span></span>
                      <span id='like'> </span>
                        <span id='share'><span id='share_txt'>SHARE</span><span id='share_circle_one'></span><span id='share_circle_two'></span></span>
                         <span id='comment' class='cmnt_cls'><img src='images/comment.png' width='32' height='32' /></span>
                         <span id='post_time'>".$posts[$i]["post_date"]."</span>
                         <br />
                         <br>
                         <br>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                      <div id='total_comments' class='total_comment_slider'>

                      </div>
                      <div id='comments'>
                            <img src='images/image.jpg' width='30' height='30' />
                        <span id='cmntbox'>
                        <textarea name='your_comment' placeholder='Say Something'></textarea>

                        <input type='submit' value='Comment' id='comment_submit' /></span>
                      </div>

            </div>
                </div>";
```

my question is that is there any way i can just add the returned ajax data from the php page to the div "center",so that my update stream won't get refreshed ?

Comment: Just a quick nit pick: Don't output all your HTML with an echo, that's going to be the root of a lot of your problems. Also, no need to concat values if you're using ", PHP will by default parse the string for variables, so you can embed the variable directly into the string. For arrays, you just wrap in {} so you'd get {$posts[$i]}

Comment: consider using [.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/). `.html()` replaces the content. I would also prefer sending only data to the page and do the layout at the client side. you may be interested in [json_encode](http://www.php.net/json_encode‎)

Comment: And, btw, facebook uses much more sophisticated ways than regular ajax calls/responses.E.g. https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=14218138919

Comment: thnx guys , and i want to append the data on the top of the div content , so i would go with prepend(),but thanks  for the valuable suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You should use [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) to fetch data dynamically. Making ajax requests every 1000ms is rather inefficient.  Here is a plugin which makes implementing WebSockets hassle free and it works with many environments php, nodejs, ruby etc:

http://socket.io/